# CanvaCard issue in Discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to generate a rank card. All the details have been fetched and properly placed in the card. Except for the details (info) on the card, the card is generated and sent. Code : https://srcb.in/lVPb3SeHYw [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZcoq.png) plus there's a warning that shows quite often whenever we generate a card (node :1236)

In the image we can see the issue clearly, except for the info everything is displayed. I've tried installing `discord-canvas` and I even installed `canvacord/@beta`but still it doesn't works for me. I've asked few of my frds to check the code and it's working for them. I've tried contacting someone from canvacord server. He said it's due to fonts. Not sure what is the actual issue and how to resolve I've been working on this so hard but can't able to resolve. I want the rank card generation with proper details and everything placed along with no warnings.